# Is there any reason to set pii or qii = 0, not 1, in t-SNE?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, tsne

Is there any reason to set $p_{ii} = 0$ or $q_{ii} = 0$ instead of 1 in t-SNE?

### SNE

[image]

[image]
$$ C = \sum_i KL(P_i || Q_i) = \sum_i \sum_j p_{i|j} \log \frac{p_{j|i}}{q_{j|i}} $$

### Symmetric SNE

[image]

[image]
$$ C = KL(P_i || Q_i) = \sum_i \sum_j p_{ij} \log \frac{p_{ji}}{q_{ji}} $$

The author of t-SNE, L. var der Maaten said below at t-SNE paper.
"For nearby datapoints, $p_{j|i}$ is relatively high, whereas for widely separated datapoints, $p_{j|i}$ will be almost infinitesimal."

I think $P_{j|i}$ or $P_{ji}$ is the similarity function of the data points.
Therefore if $j = i$, $p = 1$ is more reasonable than $p = 0$.

So, is there any reason to set $p_{ii} = 0$ or $q_{ii} = 0$ instead of 1 in t-SNE?

Comment: @utobi thanks for edit - I added some formula about Probability functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing the original article: (p. 2581, paragraph right below the equation 1)

> Because we are only interested in modeling pairwise similarities, we
>   set the value of $p_{i|i}$ to zero.

If that's a good reason, I'm not sure. But in practice I think it doesn't change anything since $p_{ii} = 0$ and $q_{ii} = 0$ **or** $p_{ii} = 1$ and $q_{ii} = 1$ both give the same value to the cost function $C$.

Intuitively I think you are right, It makes more sense to set $p_{ii} = 1$ and $q_{ii} = 1$

- [Link to original article](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/vandermaaten08a/vandermaaten08a.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! I also think that in practice setting p = 0 doesn`t change anything.

Comment: $p_{i|j}$ are supposed to sum to to 1 (when summed across $i$). How would this be possible or make sense if $p_{i|i}$ were equal to 1? This does not make sense to me. Zero is the only natural choice.